# Javascript - Grab time from a tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a bit stuck with a javascript countdown script. It is designed to grab the amount of time from a div and then count this down and submit a form.

Here is the code:

```js
function secondPassed() {
  var str=$("#countdown").text();
  var pieces = str.split(":");
  var seconds = (Number(pieces[0]) * 60) + Number(pieces[1]);
  var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);

  remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

  if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
  }

  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
  if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    document.qForm.submit();
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Question 1 of 20<time id="countdown">5:00</time></h3>
<form name="qForm">
  <input type="radio"> 219
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The issue is found in the first few lines which I have had to modify. How do I get it to grab the text from my time tag, but instead I'm stuck with it being like this:

```
var pieces = str.split(":");
```

How do I get it to pull in the time value from my time tag instead?

Comment: Are you looking for `str = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML`?

Comment: @Satpal I think so. But how do I integrate the split to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your logic can be greatly simplified. What you need to realize is that since you are reading from the `.innerHTML` of the element, you will have to update it so that you actually successfully decrement the time: otherwise you are perpetually stuck at the starting time, since you are reading from the text node and yet it is never updated.

### Step 1: Reading the `.innerHTML` of your element

In order to get the innerHTML of the `<time>` element, you can do it as simple as:

```
var pieces = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML.split(":");
```

However, we can always cache this DOM node, since we need to update its innerHTML later anyway:

```
var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
var pieces = countdown.innerHTML.split(":");
```

### Step 2: Counting down

You've got the time parsing logic correct, so all you need is to keep track of the **total seconds** left on your clock, and remember to decrement it by 1 second:

```
var totalSeconds = (Number(pieces[0]) * 60) + Number(pieces[1]);

// Countdown
totalSeconds--;
```

### Step 3. Update your `<time>` element so that countdown time is updated

Here we simply get decremented `totalSeconds`, and calculate the remaining minutes and seconds left. Minutes left is simply the total seconds divided by 60 and floored, while seconds left is simply the modulus of total seconds. You've got the calculations right to begin with, I simply made it easier to read.

Then, you want to update your countdown element's innerHTML (remember that we cahced that DOM node in step 1?). We use tenary operators to simplify the logic of adding `0` to the front of single-digit seconds:

```
// Update <time>
var currentMinutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
var currentSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;
countdown.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ':' + (currentSeconds < 10 ? '0' + currentSeconds : currentSeconds);
```

### Step 4: Check if timer has run out

This is the simple part: at the end of everything, just check if `totalSeconds` is now `0`. If it is, clear the interval and submit the form:

```
// Submit form when we hit 0
if (totalSeconds === 0) {
  window.clearInterval(countdownTimer);
  document.getElementById('qForm').submit();
}
```

---

Here is a proof-of-concept example, but I have substituted the time so that we have 5 seconds to countdown (to simplyify testing) and that the form submission is commented out and replaced by an `alert()`:

```js
function secondPassed() {
  var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
  var pieces = countdown.innerHTML.split(":");
  var totalSeconds = (Number(pieces[0]) * 60) + Number(pieces[1]);

  // Countdown
  totalSeconds--;

  // Update <time>
  var currentMinutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
  var currentSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;
  countdown.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ':' + (currentSeconds < 10 ? '0' + currentSeconds : currentSeconds);
 
  // Submit form when we hit 0
  if (totalSeconds === 0) {
    window.clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    
    alert('Will submit form!');
    // document.getElementById('qForm').submit();
  }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

```html
<h3>Question 1 of 20<br /><time id="countdown">0:05</time></h3>
<form name="qForm">
  <input type="radio"> 219
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

## Alternative recommendation: store data in HTML5 `data-` attribute

It's often not ideal to read data directly from innerHTML of a DOM node, because sometimes you might want to update the HTML without affected the stored data. In that case, you can always use the [HTML5 dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), where arbitrary data is stored in `data-` attributes.

In the code snippet below, we can store the countdown in the `date-countdown` attribute:

```
<time id="countdown" data-countdown="0:05"></time>
```

And we can simply create a helper function to synchronize the `data-countdown` value and write it to the innerHTML:

```
function updateTimer() {
  var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
  countdown.innerHTML = countdown.dataset.countdown;
}
```

You can call this function:

1. On pageload, and
2. Every time the countdown is updated

See the updated proof-of-concept below:

```js
function secondPassed() {
  var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
  var pieces = countdown.dataset.countdown.split(":");
  var totalSeconds = (Number(pieces[0]) * 60) + Number(pieces[1]);

  // Countdown
  totalSeconds--;

  // Update <time>
  var currentMinutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
  var currentSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;
  countdown.dataset.countdown = currentMinutes + ':' + (currentSeconds < 10 ? '0' + currentSeconds : currentSeconds);
  
  // Update innerHTML
  updateTimer();
 
  // Submit form when we hit 0
  if (totalSeconds === 0) {
    window.clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    
    alert('Will submit form!');
    // document.getElementById('qForm').submit();
  }
}

function updateTimer() {
  var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');
  countdown.innerHTML = countdown.dataset.countdown;
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
updateTimer();
```

```html
<h3>Question 1 of 20<br /><time id="countdown" data-countdown="0:05"></time></h3>
<form name="qForm">
  <input type="radio"> 219
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Terry. This is an amazing answer, thank you very much. I think I learnt a thing of two because of this.

Comment: @Jimmy You're welcome! I have updated my answer to include an alternative recommendation, where you store the countdown data in a `data-countdown` (or any arbitrarily named `data-` attribute) instead. This is because the textnode of an element is typically used for display purposes, and we should read/write data using `data-` instead. It's not an absolute requirement, but a good guideline to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why you would want to be select this from the DOM, would it not just be better to know you are calculating 5 minutes and save yourself the hassle of parsing the value from the DOM.

Alternatively, set the 'datetime' property of the  tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp

See below for an example of reading this:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_time_datetime.asp

Comment: Because the quiz time will be different on different pages and it allows me to keep the javascript file static and consistent

Comment: Well, the datetime property will do the trick but beware obviously if this is fundamental to the application a user could easily tamper with the values in the DOM using Chrome and then give them self a bunch more time.

Could have an array of page with timings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

```
    var countdownTimer;
function secondPassed() {
    var str =  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML;
    var pieces = str.split(":");
    var seconds = (Number(pieces[0]) * 60) + Number(pieces[1]);
    console.log(seconds);

    var minutes = 0;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    //            document.qForm.submit();
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes+':'+ (seconds%60);

}
countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use momentJS to convert the time into a duration (a little overkill though) and setting an end date with it, like so:

```js
function convertStringToDuration( s ) {
  // Just in case, if you plan to use hours as well in the future :)
  const parameterNames = [ 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds' ];
  const parts = s.split( ':' );
  
  // Generate moment.duration parameters
  const parameters = parameterNames.slice( -parts.length ).reduce( ( result, param, index ) => {
    result[ param ] = parseInt( parts[ index ], 10 );
    return result;
  }, {} );
  
  return moment.duration( parameters );
}

function pass( timer, element, end, callback ) {
  // get the current time
  const now = moment();
  // calculate duration
  let duration = end - now;
  if ( duration <= 0 ) {
    duration = 0;
    clearInterval( timer );
    if ( typeof callback === 'function' ) {
      callback();
    }
  }
  
  // and format time
  const formatted = moment.utc( duration ).format( 'm:ss' );
  element.innerText = formatted;
}

function action() {
  console.log( 'Done' );
}

const countdown = document.querySelector( '#countdown' );
const duration = convertStringToDuration( countdown.innerText );

// set end time
const end = moment().add( duration );

let countdownTimer = setInterval( () => pass( countdownTimer, countdown, end, action ), 250 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<h3>Question 1 of 20<br><time id="countdown">5:00</time></h3>
<form name="qForm">
  <input type="radio"> 219
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```